# How to rename file without overwriting existing?

Tags: node.js, fs

Lets say I have two files:

`/1.txt`

`/2.txt`

Now if I call `fs.rename('/1.txt', '/2.txt')`, it will replace `2.txt` with `1.txt`.

They say this is how rename works it Linux and all. But I don't want to replace if a file on a new path exists already. Ideally I want to throw some error on that, like `EEXIST`. Using `fs.existsSync`, `fs.stat` or other checks before renaming introduces race condition as I understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To avoid race condition you will need some kind of locking mechanism.

On Linux system it's pretty standard to use a lockfile - generally it's an empty file or directory that serves as a check that some sequence of operations is taking place. Similar to database row/table locking creating and removing of lockfile is atomic - the rest of the operations are not.

I would use [proper-lockfile](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proper-lockfile) package and `move` from [fs-extra](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-extra) for this:

```
const lockfile = require('proper-lockfile');
const fs = require('fs-extra');

lockfile.lock('some/file')
  .then(() => fs.move('/tmp/file', 'some/file'))
  .finally(() => lockfile.unlock('some/file'));
```

Also note that any logic working with `some/file` has to respect the `lockfile` otherwise the race condition would still exists.

Comment: I've had a look at the package code and as I can see this package uses checks before renaming too, so I suppose it has a race condition.

Comment: Sorry, didn't noticed the race condition requirement... you will have to create a lockfile - AFAIK there is no other way.

Comment: Could you please provide more info on creating a lockfile and using it for renaming files or directories? Should I use `lockfile` package for that?

Comment: Answer updated - I hope it makes sense. Let me know if it works for you. There are other things you could do. For example you can play with permissions

Comment: Didn't test it yet but I'm sure this will do the job. Thank you for your time.